# Glyphicons no longer supported in Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, glyphicons

I've read, from official docs, that Glyphicons were dropped from Bootstrap 4.

Today, in my searching for implementing checkbox button, I've found one snippet that I appreciate very much:

[Snippet for Checkbox 3.0](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/6o0P)

The problem is that this version is for Bootstrap 3.0, where Glyph were supported yet.

So I've 2 question:

1. Which is a good alternative to Glyphicons? Or there is a way to use them yet?
2. How I may change the html and js snippet above to make it working with Bootstrap 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1 - Which is a good alternative to Glyphicons? Or there is a way to use them yet?**

The best alternative IMHO: http://fontawesome.io/icons/

**2 - How I may change the html and js snippet above to make it working with Bootstrap 4?**

[jQuery Checkbox Buttons - Bootstrap 4](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/7nQMK)

You need to change the JS:

```
settings = {
    on: {
        icon: 'fa fa-square-o'
    },
    off: {
        icon: 'fa fa-check-square-o'
    }
};
```

And the CSS class `.hidden` is now deprecated so Bootstrap recommends to use `style="display: none"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I agree @nerijunior Font Awesome icons is the best alternative, here is how, tested:

To use Font Awesome icons, add the following to your HTML page (No downloading or installation is required) Given Example below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
  
<body>

<div class="container">  
  <h1>My Icons <i class="fas fa-heart"></i></h1>
  <p>An icon along with some text: <i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i></p> 
</div>
  
<div class="container">
  <p>Others:</p>
  <i class="fas fa-cloud"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-coffee"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-car"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-file"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

source: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_icons.asp